# UltimateListCtrl - selections and sorting

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.x

i wrote a little python program with wxpython and ulc for a personal database.
I thought i was finished and finally imported all the data from an original access database an now was faced with a problem. Having nearly 1000 entries in the ulc (instead of my 50 from the development) slows it so much down it becomes unuseable. 
So i started to rewrite everything using the virtual mode to fix this problem. But now im faced with another problem.

I have a checkbox in the listctrl to select multiple people and im also using the ColumnSorterMixin. In normal mode when sorting the list in a different way the selections made in the list would stay correctly but in virtual mode the selection stays on the row and not on the real item.

For example if you selected the third row and then resort the list, the item that was in the third row is now in the fourth row, but the third row is still selected. Am i doing something wrong? i tried checkboxes as well as selections using the ctrl key. Both have the same problem.

Here is my test code for the problem...

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

data = {
1 : ("John Doe", "Madeup Road 11\nFakeTown", "000-383783763"),
2 : ("Jane Doe", "Madeup Road 11\nFakeTown", "000-383783763"),
3 : ("Max Mustermann", "Madeup Road 16\nFakeTown", "043-3434763"),
4 : ("Myself", "Fake Road 9\nFakeTown", "323-3843457773"),
}


class mylist(ULC.UltimateListCtrl, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_VIRTUAL|ULC.ULC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_USER_ROW_HEIGHT|ULC.ULC_SINGLE_SEL|ULC.ULC_VRULES|ULC.ULC_HRULES)
        self.SetUserLineHeight(40)
        self.itemDataMap = data
        self.itemIndexMap = data.keys()
        self.SetItemCount(len(data))
        self.table_fields=['Name','Street','Phone']
        field_index=0

        for field in self.table_fields:
            info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
            info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT
            info._image = []
            info._format = wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT
            info._kind = 1
            info._text = field
            info._font= wx.Font(13, wx.ROMAN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
            self.InsertColumnInfo(field_index, info)
            self.SetColumnWidth(field_index,175)
            field_index += 1


        self.checked = []
        self.Bind(ULC.EVT_LIST_ITEM_CHECKING, self.OnCheck)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColumn)

        #mixins
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)

        #sort by column (2), A->Z ascending order (1)
        self.SortListItems(0, 1)


    def SortItems(self,sorter=cmp):
        items = list(self.itemDataMap.keys())
        items.sort(sorter)
        self.itemIndexMap = items

        # redraw the list
        self.Refresh()

    def OnColumn(self, e):
        self.Update()
        e.Skip()

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self

    def OnCheck(self, event):
        item_column = (event.m_itemIndex, event.m_item.GetColumn())
        print item_column
        try:
            idx = self.checked.index(item_column)
        except ValueError:
            idx = None

        if idx == None:
            self.checked.append(item_column)
        else:
            del(self.checked[idx])
        self.Refresh()

    def getColumnText(self, index, col):
        item = self.GetItem(index, col)
        return item.GetText()

    def OnGetItemText(self, item, col):
        index=self.itemIndexMap[item]
        s = self.itemDataMap[index][col]
        return s

    def OnGetItemColumnImage(self, item, col):
        return []

    def OnGetItemImage(self, item):
        return []

    def OnGetItemAttr(self, item):
        return None

    def OnGetItemTextColour(self, item, col):
        return None

    def OnGetItemToolTip(self, item, col):
        return None

    def OnGetItemKind(self, item):
        return 1

    def OnGetItemColumnKind(self, item, col):
        if col==0:
            return self.OnGetItemKind(item)
        return 0

    def OnGetItemColumnCheck(self, item, column):
        item_column = (item, column)
        if item_column in self.checked:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "UltimateListCtrl in wx.LC_VIRTUAL mode", size=(700, 600))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.listctrl = listCtrl = mylist(panel)
        sizer.Add(listCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Layout()
        self.CenterOnScreen()
        self.Show()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = TestFrame(None)
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Is this possible in a virtual ListCtrl or am i doing something wrong?

Im testing this on Windows 8.1, Python 2.7.10 and wxPython 3.0.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit** Noticed you were testing on 3.0.2, so I updated my demo from before and tested using the same wx version (and Python 2.7.11) instead of wx 3.0.3 'Phoenix' that I was using.
The answer to you question is: Yes, it's possible.
More than one way would satisfy, but here's a working demo you can paste in its entirety and run in its own py file for testing.
This demo is tested on wx version 3.0.2.0 osx-cocoa (classic) and meets the following criteria:

> Lists a thousand records, uses ULC in virtual mode, sorts on any column, checks multiple items, can check/uncheck using select-all box, preserves item checks when sorting rather than staying in position, doesn't become slow/unusable like your original version that led you here.

```
    import wxversion
    wxversion.select(['3.0'])  #for me this switches from 'Phoenix' to 'Classic'
    import wx; print wx.version();
    from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC
    from wx.lib.mixins import listctrl as listmix


    class mylist(ULC.UltimateListCtrl, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
        """
        Sortable list with check box for each row and a 'select all' box
        When sorting, the checkboxes follow the data, rather than staying on their row
        """
        def __init__(self, parent):
            ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1,
                                          agwStyle=ULC.ULC_VIRTUAL | ULC.ULC_REPORT# | ULC_SINGLE_SEL
                                          )
            datasource = Records()
            self.itemDataMap = datasource.data
            self.itemIndexMap = self.itemDataMap.keys()
            self.itemCheckedMap1 = set()
            self.itemCheckedMap2 = set()
            self.table_fields = ["id", "rockcol", "papercol", "scissorscol", "lizardcol"]
            field_index = 0
            for field in self.table_fields:
                info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
                masktoset = ULC.ULC_MASK_TEXT
                if field_index == 0:
                    masktoset |= ULC.ULC_MASK_KIND | ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
                    kindtoset = ULC.ULC_KIND_CHECK = wx.ITEM_CHECK
                    widthtoset = 60
                    info.Check(False)
                else:
                    widthtoset = ULC.ULC_AUTOSIZE
                info.SetText(field)
                info.SetKind(kindtoset)
                info.SetMask(masktoset)
                self.InsertColumnInfo(field_index, info)
                self.SetItemCount(len(datasource.data))
                self.SetColumnWidth(field_index, widthtoset)
                field_index += 1
            self.Bind(ULC.EVT_LIST_ITEM_CHECKING, self.OnSetItemCheck)
            self.Bind(ULC.EVT_LIST_COL_CHECKING, self.OnSetColumnCheck)
            self.Bind(ULC.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColClick, self)
            listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, len(self.table_fields))  #binds col click event
            #self.SortListItems(1, 1)


    ####
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # bound event handling
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        def OnSetItemCheck(self, e):
            x1 = e.m_itemIndex
            y1 = e.EventObject.itemCheckedMap1
            x2 = int(e.m_item._text)
            y2 = e.EventObject.itemCheckedMap2
            for x, y in (x1, y1), (x2, y2):
                if x not in y:
                    y.add(x)
                else:
                    y.remove(x)
            self.Refresh()

        def OnSetColumnCheck(self, e):
            e.EventObject.GetColumn(e.m_col)._checked = x = not e.EventObject.GetColumn(e.m_col)._checked
            if x:
                e.EventObject.itemCheckedMap1 = set(e.EventObject.itemIndexMap)
            else:
                e.EventObject.itemCheckedMap1.clear()
            self.Refresh()

        def OnColClick(self, e):
            self.Refresh()
            e.Skip()

        def GetListCtrl(self): #for sorter init
            return self

        def SortItems(self, sorter=cmp):
            self.itemIndexMap.sort(sorter)
            self.Refresh()

        def SortListItems(self, col=-1, ascending=1):
            self.fix()
            super(mylist, self).SortListItems(col, ascending)

        def fix(self):
            pass

        def OnSortOrderChanged(self):
            self.itemCheckedMap1 = set(i for i, x in enumerate(self.itemIndexMap) if x in self.itemCheckedMap2)


    ####
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # overrides for 'virtual' mode support
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        def OnGetItemText(self, item, col):
            idx = self.itemIndexMap[item]
            return str(self.itemDataMap[idx][col])

        def OnGetItemTextColour(self, item, col):
            return None

        def OnGetItemToolTip(self, item, col):
            return None

        def OnGetItemColumnImage(self, item, column=0):
            return []

        def OnGetItemCheck(self, idx):
            return idx in self.itemCheckedMap1

        def OnGetItemColumnCheck(self, item, column=0):
            return self.OnGetItemCheck(item)

        def OnGetItemKind(self, itemidx):
            return wx.ITEM_CHECK

        def OnGetItemColumnKind(self, itemidx, columnidx):
            if self.GetColumn(columnidx)._kind == wx.ITEM_CHECK:
                return self.OnGetItemKind(itemidx)
            return wx.ITEM_NORMAL


    class Records:
        """
        Generates some unsorted data for testing sort and checkbox preservation
        """
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = {}
            self.makedataset(1000)

        def makedataset(self, rcount):
            for ci in xrange(rcount):
                c1 = str(hash(ci^2*2))
                c2 = str(hash(ci^3*2))
                c3 = str(hash(ci^4*2))
                c4 = str(hash(ci^1*2))
                self.data[ci] = ci, c1, c2, c3, c4


    class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "virtual-mode ULC", size=(800, 300))
            panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.listctrl = mylist(panel)
            sizer.Add(self.listctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            panel.SetSizer(sizer)
            sizer.Layout()
            self.Show()

    mySandbox = wx.App()
    mySandbox.SetTopWindow(TestFrame())
    mySandbox.MainLoop()

    exit()
```

The strategy used is to update the array of checked boxes each time the sort order is changed. There are other ways, but this one relies on an id column being in the displayed data.